# python invoke script with arguments two folders above

Tags: python, command-line, import

Lets assume the file structure as below.

```
C:\folder1
       file1.py
       folder2
           folder3
               file3.py
```

I want file3.py to run file1 from command line with its arguments. Do I need to import folder1 or file1? How? How to call the script?

I tried the following

```
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(currentdir, '../../'))
```

Comment: If you are going to execute file1.py as an executable by calling subprocess.Popen() or similar from inside file3.py, then just off the top of my head you can specify absolute path to file1.py, relatively path to file1.py or change the current working directory using os.chdir(), etc, etc. What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run external program in Python, some common choices are [subprocess.Popen, subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

Take subprocess.Popen and your folder structure as example, here is file3.py:

```
import os
import subprocess

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
target_script = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, '..', '..', 'file1.py'))
arg1 = 'test_value'
call_args = ['python', target_script, arg1]
subprocess.Popen(call_args)
```

The above codes will run file1.py in a subprocess, and pass 'arg1' to it.

---

More Pythonic solution is: put a [__init__.py file](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) under "folder1", "folder2" and "folder3", then Python will treat these directories as packages.

In file1.py:

```
import sys

def func1(arg):
    print 'func1 received: %s' % arg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # better to validate sys.argv here
    func1(sys.argv[1])
```

In this way, you can import file1.func1 in other python scripts, as well as run file1.py in command line directly.

Then, file3.py:

```
from ...file1 import func1
# "." means current dir, ".." means one level above, and "..." is 2 levels above

func1('test_value')
```

To execute file3.py: go to folder1's parent folder (i.e. C:\ in your example), then execute `python -m folder1.folder2.folder3.file3`

This solution may look more complicated, but with your project going bigger, well organized package structure will benefit more.

Comment: target_script = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, '..', 'file1.py'))

This only goes up by one level into folder2, but file1 is in folder1 though.. so how to go up one more level?

Comment: target_script = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(currentdir, '..', '..', '/file1.py'))........ This works.

Comment: There a little mistake in my original codes: `current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(...))` it already goes 2 levels above, so there is only one `'..'` inside `path.join()`. I modified my codes